# Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ being equal P-almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory

Here is an associated example that came with the definition of two random variables being P-almost surely. I will also write the definition below.

**Definition.** Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ be a probability space and let $X,Y$ be random variables. Then, $X$ equals $Y$ $P$-almost surely if $$P(\{w\in\Omega\ \text{such that} X(w)=Y(w)\}=1.$$

**Example.** Suppose $X$ is normally distributed and $Y$ is defined by $$Y(w)= \begin{cases}X(w) & X(w)\neq\pi\\1000& X(w)=\pi\end{cases}.$$ Then $X=Y$ $P$-almost surely.

---

**Confusion.** In the case of $Y(w)=1000$; how is the condition of X being equal to Y P almost surely? Because $X(w)=\pi$ and $Y(w)=1000$ here, two values which aren't equal, so the condition doesn't hold there? Or is the fact that X being not equal to Y at only one point out of the whole sample space negligible in regards to the definition?

Comment: "Or is the fact that X being not equal to Y at only one point out of the whole sample space negligible in regards to the definition?" Precisely. One way to look at this is that $\Omega$ is uncountable, so the value of $X$ or $Y$ at one point is negligible.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, do feel free to write this as an official answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: I would hesitate to write this as an answer due to the lack of rigor, but if someone else wants to then by all means.

Comment: I suppose that's understandable. In any case, thanks again for clearing things up even if it is as you feel, in an "informal" manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bad" subset is measure $0$, so it is negligible as @Math1000 pointed out. The result can be obtained after taking partition of $\Omega = \{X=\pi\}\cup\{X\neq\pi\}$.
$$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\P(X=Y) = \P(X=Y, X\neq\pi) + \P(X=Y, X=\pi) = \P(X\neq\pi) + 0 = 1+ 0 = 1.$$

Comment: Ah didn't think of it as a partition like that, thank you very much!